# SoapSerializationEnvelope Error in sqlcipher

Tags: android, soap-serialization

I am geeting a strange message

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope

When i add 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@arr' in dependencies. Otherwise it appication works fine.

And this problem is only in lower version android like 4.0,4.4 etc. on other mobile on runtime code is able to locate **SoapSerializationEnvelope**

Comment: Did you find any updated version of the library?

Comment: This is the updated one. I am not able to understand how this is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the error.
I am using lots of library and multidex was **disable**.

In Gradle i added

```
defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

and in Applicaiton class

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}

Solved My Problem.